# One click snap photo in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to snap a photo and have it uploaded after clicking on the button. Is this how you would take a picture and upload it by clicking on a one button click?

```
function snap(){
      // Take a picture using the devices camera and retrieve an image as a
      // base64-encoded string.
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}    

<button onclick="snap();">Snap</button>
```

Comment: What this will do is: 1) open the default camera application, 2) allow the user to take a photo, then 3) return to your app and run the `onPhotoDataSuccess` function with a base64-encoded data URI as the first argument. What do you *want* it to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want to save the picture irrelevant of whether the user chooses to keep it or not, then set the [saveToPhotoAlbum parameter](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) of the getPicture method to true. Otherwise if you want to upload the picture to a server somewhere, you would need more work. Take a look at these articles that give examples how this is accomplished:

- [Capturing and Uploading Photos on iOS with Cordova](http://metabates.com/2012/04/15/capturing-and-uploading-photos-on-ios-with-phonegap/)
- [Uploading Photos from Mobile Web Applications](http://simonguest.com/2012/07/06/uploading-photos-from-mobile-web-applications/)